# SELECT * FROM table A and count the number of corresponding rows in Table B that match a specific field

Tags: mysql, database, select, join

I have two tables: "series" and "product"

"series" holds the names of series of books, "product" has the details of individual book titles.

So something like this:

```
Series Table:
id      series_name               series_description
1       Lord of the Rings         Trilogy of fantasy books recently made into film
2       A Song of Ice and Fire    Epic series of novels currently showing on HBO
3       Harry Potter              Famous Children's book series also loved by adults

Product Table:
id      product_name              series_id     author             etc...
1       Fellowship of the Ring    1             JRR Tolkien
2       The Two Towers            1             JRR Tolkien
3       Return of the King        1             JRR Tolkien
4       A Game of Thrones         2             George R R Martin
5       A Clash of Kings          2             George R R Martin
6       A Storm of Swords         2             George R R Martin
7       A Feast for Crows         2             George R R Martin
8       A Dance with Dragons      2             George R R Martin
9       Harry Potter and the...   3             JK Rowling
etc.
```

I want to SELECT * FROM series, and COUNT(*) FROM product so that the query returns a table containing the series info, with the number of products in the database corresponding to each series appended as the last column of the table.  I'd also like to do this by genre, so there is an additional WHERE clause in there somewhere.  It would look something like this, if selecting "Fantasy and Magic" as the genre:

```
id      series_name               series_description         number_of_products
1       Lord of the Rings         Trilogy of Fantasy...      3
2       A Song of Ice and Fire    Epic Series of Novels...   5
3       Harry Potter              Famous Children's book...  7
```

I think I may need a LEFT JOIN but my best attempts so far have been in vein.

This is what I have so far, but I think it's probably totally wrong.

```
SELECT  series.id,                                   
series.series_name,                                         
series.publisher_id,                                       
series.description, 
series.image, 
COUNT (product.*) as nRows 
FROM series 
LEFT OUTER JOIN product
ON series.id = product.series_id                    
WHERE series.genre = 'Fantasy and Magic'
GROUP BY ... (do I need a GROUP BY?)
```

Any help at all would be really appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're nearly there just group by the same attributes you are selecting (except the aggregate count).

Answer (score 7):

Almost there. Try this.

```
SELECT  series.id,                                   
series.series_name,                                         
series.publisher_id,                                       
series.description, 
series.image, 
COUNT (product.id) as nRows 
FROM series 
LEFT OUTER JOIN product
ON series.id = product.series_id                    
WHERE series.genre = 'Fantasy and Magic'
GROUP BY series.id,                                   
series.series_name,                                         
series.publisher_id,                                       
series.description, 
series.image
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I feel a bit stupid having almost got there and failed at the last fence, but I appreciate your help.  Got there in the end - it's working nice and fast now :)  I'd vote you up, but I'm 2 points short of being able to do so.

Comment: No problem. Note that MySQL will let you get away without specifying all the GROUP BY fields but this isn't standard SQL (so it is probably best to keep in the habit of specifying them all). GROUP BY specifies all the fields which have the same value on rows on which you will group up the values. Without a GROUP BY in this query you would get a single row returned containing a count of ALL the matching product rows, while the series columns would have values from unspecified rows.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d526/4) help;

```
select s.id, 
   s.series_name, 
   s.series_description, 
   (select count(*) from Products p where p.series_id = s.id) number_of_products 
from Series s
```

Comment: That would likely be very slow, as each row of the series table would result in a subselect on the products table. Could possibly do a JOIN on a subselect, with the subselect getting the series id and the count of all records per series id.